# Wordpress add topbar HTML linking to original referrer website

Tags: php, wordpress, session, url, cookies

I have an eCommerce website that is currently in the staging environment (suppose abc.com). I have been trying to figure out a way to achieve the following with a simple function.

I want to add a link to the original referrer page (let' say xyz.com) on every page of abc.com. I am stuck as i am not able to save the original referrer URL in a PHP session inside a function.

I tried this,

```
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'custom_referrer_url', 10, 2);
function custom_referrer_url($new_value, $field){
    $get_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //stores the value of the referring URL
    $parse = parse_url($get_url); //parses the referring URL
    $new_value = $parse['host']; //stores the domain value of the referring URL
  }
  return $new_value;
}
```

But the browser is changing the referrer URL to the previous page URL (abc.com/referrer) when the user is navigating to a different page. But I need to save xyz.com as the original referrer and keep showing the HTML top bar so that the users can have a way to return to xyz.com whenever they want.

Comment: You should avoid relying on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` since you never can count on it being available or set. There are browsers/routers etc that won't pass that header along for privacy reasons.

Comment: What is the alternative I can use?